# lyx - is it possible to include content from a few commands, perhaps in a script?

Tags: lyx, automation, scripts

Let me try to simplify the problem that I'm facing. I am writing a handbook and I want to include the output of maaaaaany commands (and some content of some text files) in the document. I m doing the obvious:

- I run a command
- I copy the command and the output
- I add a Program Listing
- I copy the command/output and style it if necessary (lines numbers? No line numbers? and such)

I could also modify some text files that I am including as well (also in Program Listing)... or it could be a few lines... suppose that I could define the lines that I copy over with a regex.

So... is it possible to, instead of having to do this process of copying over by hand, tell lyx somehow to run a few commands (or perhaps a script) and include the output in a Program Listing block? So that it could be built on the fly?

Comment: Take a look at knitr. Many languages are now supported: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/language-engines.html

Comment: Will take a look

Comment: By the way, LyX has a simple example file. Go to Help > Specific Manuals > Knitr. Before compiling it, you will need knitr (and thus R) installed and you might need to go to Tools > Reconfigure and restart LyX.